# Write to file as CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm using this bit of code that I found on stackoverflow to write data to a file.

```
begin
  file = File.open("/tmp/some_file", "w")
  file.write("your text") 
rescue IOError => e
  #some error occur, dir not writable etc.
ensure
  file.close unless file == nil
end
```

where it says your text if I put one of my variable names it will fill in the correct string used as that variable but ideally what I want is to have more than one variable in the output ideally in CSV. Something like:

```
file.write(var1 ^ var2 ^ var3)
```

Where each of my variables are seperated by a carrot symbol. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually There is a gem for CSV although there is a CSV library in standard ruby library.

Take a look at examples and you will find out that writing CSV files in ruby is much more easier that you thought.

http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/classes/FasterCSV.html

http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/

Ruby Stdlib: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-generate

Comment: There is no need to use FasterCSV in Ruby 1.9+, as Ruby's stdlib CSV *is* FasterCSV. Only use FasterCSV if you're using Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Never knew that the C in CSV stands for Carrot.

Comment: Looks like I'm running: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [universal-darwin10.0] How do I update this on OSX?

Comment: @Tony You can install rvm, checkout the rvm.io website

Comment: Can someone provide some examples on how I would now accomplish the original post using stdlib CSV?